# Проблема с текстом в битрикс после обновления PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, битрикс

После обновления PHP на сайте стали вылезать следующие иероглифы

Подскажите как можно это исправить
Кодировка на сайте windows-1251
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]